# Como manipular uma janela windows no python?

Tags: python

Seguinte, tenho um código bem simples que apenas abre um programa exe

```
import os caminho = os.startfile(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Nox\bin\nox.exe")
```

Porém, ao executar, a janela do aplicativo vem minimizada e com um tamanho muito grande, como poderia fazer para diminuir o tamanho da janela e não deixar ela minimizada?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca `pygetwindow`. Para instalar ela, basta digitar:

> pip install PyGetWindow

Para começar, importe `pygetwindow` e depois obtenha a janela utilizando a função `getWindowsWithTitle(title)`. Existem outras funções para obter uma janela, mas eu recomendo esta, pois aqui você só precisa colocar o título da janela.

Depois disso, você pode utilizar o método `resizeTo(newWidth,newHeight)` para redimensionar a janela e o método `activate()` para fazer a janela aparecer. Veja esse exemplo abaixo:

```
import pygetwindow

title = 'Stack Overflow em Português - Google Chrome'

window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle(title)[0]
window.activate()
window.resizeTo(1280,720)
```

Comment: Exatamente o que eu estava procurando, muito obrigado